# Prove that a map is open in the Zariski topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Say $k$ is an algebraically closed field and define the equivalence relation on $k^{n+1}$ given by $x \sim y \iff x=\lambda y $ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{k}^{\times}$. Clearly $\mathbb{P}^{n} = k^{n+1}/\sim$. Let the map $q:k^{n+1} \setminus 0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n}$ be the quotient map that sends $x$ to its equivalence class. I have to show that it is an open map (for the Zariski topology). Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition for the topology on $\mathbb{P^n}$?

Comment: Quotient topology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

1. $q^{-1}(q(U))=\bigcup_{\lambda\in k^{\times}}\lambda U$
2. Multiplication by $\lambda\neq 0$ is a homeomorphism as for basic opens $\lambda D(f)=D(f(\frac{1}{\lambda}(\cdot))) $